# SAP Crystal Reports not working in the Server after upgrading to .net framework 4.6 eventhough we upgraded the reports version to 15

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, .net-4.6, crystal-reports-server

SAP Crystal Reports are not working in the Server after upgrading to .net framework 4.6 even though we upgraded the reports version to 15. The same is working fine in my local machine withe .net framework version 4.6 and SAP reports version 15.

Let me know If I missed any steps on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per SAP's knowledge base Microsoft changed the way they name folders within /aspnet_client/system_web/ with each update of .NET. The easiest workaround is to uninstall .NET 4.6.* and reboot your server. Other workarounds are described in the KB article.

SAP KB: https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/0002250097